# Adjust image in column bootstrap (responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when I'm trying to show different images with bootstrap. These images are not adjust to column (and row also). Inside of image tag I have put .img-responsive but it has height:auto property.
I'm going to show an example to explain my problem.

[image]

Section div

```
<div class="row">
                <c:forEach items="${images}" var="images" varStatus="status">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                            <a href="<c:url value='images/upload/${images.nameImage}'/>" title="Test" data-gallery> 
                                <c:if test="${images.extension == 'jpg' || images.extension == 'png'
                                            || images.extension == 'gif' || image.extension == 'bmp'
                                            || images.extension == 'jpeg'}">
                                    <img src="<c:url value='images/upload/${images.nameImage}'/>" class="img-responsive"/>
                                </c:if>
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
        </div>
```

I have tried to put width and height inside img tag to put some size but it has not worked.

can somebody help me?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Consider revising. I don't understand your question?

Comment: Try to fix the height of each image..so that they acquire a fix height regardless of their dimenstion

Comment: Before I put this `<img src="<c:url value='images/upload/${images.nameImage}'/>" class="img-responsive" height="200"/>` but it was same and when I tried to put `<img src="<c:url value='images/upload/${images.nameImage}'/>" class="img-responsive" style=height=200px"/>` but it didn't readjust